# Anchor behaving differently on different pages

Tags: html

[prekvalifikujse.com](http://prekvalifikujse.com/)

You can go on this website and check from **index** and **kontakt** page when you hover **srednje skole** -> **tehnicka skola** -> **press any link on the list** it wont do anything, but when you enter **tehnicka skola** page, and try from that page to enter any item on list it works just fine and scrolling between headings.

Only thing that worked is **right click** -> **open in new tab** and it send me directly to that heading on **tehnicka skola** page so i considered doing `target="_blank"` but that wont work eather from **index** and **kontakt** page.

```
<?= SITE_URL ?> --- is defined on php app for prekvalifikujse.com/
```

First page with navigation menu (only one piece of code where is that part that wont work):

```
<div class="col-12">
    <ul id="nav_tabs" class="main-navigation fadeInLeft">
        <li class="item"><a class="nav_links white" href="<?= SITE_URL ?>">Pocetna</a></li>
        <li class="item"><a class="nav_links white" href="#">Fakulteti</a></li>
        <li class="item"><a class="nav_links white" href="#">Srednje Skole</a>
            <ul>                                
                <li><a href="<?= SITE_URL ?>srednje_skole/tehnicka_skola">Tehnicka Skola</a>
                <ul>                            
                    <li><a href="<?= SITE_URL ?>srednje_skole/tehnicka_skola#sts1">Elektrotehničar informacionih tehnologija</a></li>
                    <li><a href="<?= SITE_URL ?>srednje_skole/tehnicka_skola#sts2">Administrator racunarskih mreza</a></li>
                    <li><a href="<?= SITE_URL ?>srednje_skole/tehnicka_skola#sts3">Elektrotehničar računara</a></li>
                    <li><a href="<?= SITE_URL ?>srednje_skole/tehnicka_skola#sts4">Građevinski tehničar niskogradnje</a></li>
                    <li><a href="<?= SITE_URL ?>srednje_skole/tehnicka_skola#sts5">Dekorater zidnih površina (moler)</a></li>
                    <li><a href="<?= SITE_URL ?>srednje_skole/tehnicka_skola#sts6">Rukovalac građevinskom mehanizacijom</a></li>
                    <li><a href="<?= SITE_URL ?>srednje_skole/tehnicka_skola#sts7">Keramičar, teracer, pećar</a></li>
                    <li><a href="<?= SITE_URL ?>srednje_skole/tehnicka_skola#sts8">Zidar fasader</a></li>
                    <li><a href="<?= SITE_URL ?>srednje_skole/tehnicka_skola#sts9">Kuvar</a></li>
                    <li><a href="<?= SITE_URL ?>srednje_skole/tehnicka_skola#sts10">Kulinarski tehnicar</a></li>
                    <li><a href="<?= SITE_URL ?>srednje_skole/tehnicka_skola#sts11">Automehaničar</a></li>
                    <li><a href="<?= SITE_URL ?>srednje_skole/tehnicka_skola#sts12">Tehničar drumskog saobraćaja/<br>Saobraćajno-transportni tehničar</a></li>
                    <li><a href="<?= SITE_URL ?>srednje_skole/tehnicka_skola#sts13">Vozač motornih vozila-specijalista</a></li>
                </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
     </ul>
```

Second page(tehnicka skola) with some of content that has div with id that should be pulled from  tag:

```
<div class="default_width">
<div class="bcg_for_txt">
    <div class="txt_for_schools">
        <h3 class="center_text">Imate završen trogodišnji smer i želite naknadno da upišete četvrtu godinu? 
        Zanima vas vanredno školovanje za smer elekrotehničar računara? Potrebna vam je prekvalifikacija za smer elekrotehničar računara? Niste zadovoljni zanimanjem koje ste završili?
        Popunite upitnik i ostalo prepustite nama
        </h3><br><br>
        <div id="sts1"><br><br><br><h1 class="center_text">Elektrotehničar informacionih tehnologija</h1></div><br><br>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Check your console for errors

Comment: if you mean console in my editing program it's not showing any error. I'm new to this so i dont know how to check what error can be.

Comment: `functions.js?v=1558447828:61 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined`. You have a script blocking execution of the default link behavior.

Comment: No I mean the browser console. Press F12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your smooth scroll script is errorring because an element with ID matching the hash doesn't exist. You may want to do a path check before applying that behavior:

```
if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') === this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') 
  && location.hostname === this.hostname) {
    // do smooth scroll
}
```

You might also check for the element:

```
if ($(hash).length) { ... }
```

Comment: Please don't ask new questions in a comment.